# Poset with atoms that isn't atomic

Tags: order-theory

An atomic set is defined as:

```
A partially ordered set with a least element 0 is atomic if every
element b > 0 has an atom a below it, that is, there is some a such 
that b ≥ a :> 0.
```

Isn't this equal to saying: "a poset has atoms"? If a poset has atoms, isn't it automatically atomic? Of course the same applies to coatoms, and coatomic.

Comment: The poset $0,1/2,1/3,1/4,...$ with the usual order from the reals has no atoms.

Comment: A poset is atomic  if EVERY element has an atom below it. What if there is exactly  one atom $x$ and if $y$ is an element that such that no $z$ satisfies $(z\leq x\land z\leq y)$?

Comment: @totoro  Um... how does that address the question?  That set has no atoms and isn't atomic.

Comment: @fleablood Read the question.

Comment: I read the question, did you?  The question asks why isn't the definition "A set is atomic if every element has an atom below it" and the definition "A set is atomic if it has atoms" the same.  Pointing out that some sets will have no atoms isn't relevant.  Such a set would not be atomic by either definition.

Comment: @fleablood If you can't see how it is relevant. That is your own limitation. Think harder. I am not interested in walking you through it.

Comment: @totoro If someone asks why isosceles triangles aren't all equilateral, pointing out that some triangles are scalene is not relevant and does not address the question.  Pointing out that not all posets have atoms does nothing to clarify the difference between a poset having atoms and being atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no".  It is possible that a poset has *some* atoms, and also some elements that do not have atoms below them.

For example, consider the ground set $\mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}\cup \{i\}$, with the usual order on $\mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}$, and the extra relation $i>0$ and no others (i.e. $i$ is incomparable to all nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Q}^{\ge 0}$).  Now, $i$ is an atom, but there are no other atoms, and the poset is not atomic.

---

A few extra thoughts:
The example above satisfies the "has atoms" criterion but not the "atomic"  criterion.  It is also possible to go the other way.  Consider the poset containing only $0$ and nothing else.  It satisfies the "atomic" criterion vacuously, but does not satisfy the "has atoms" criterion.